# Controling Light With Photoresistor And Serial Communication - Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, light

I'm trying to turn a light "On" and "Off" with Arduino using a Relay, Photo-resistor and Serial Communication. The problem come in to play when I try to turn the light Off when the Photo-resistor is receiving a low value and has received an instruction via Serial Communication to prevent the "IF" statement from activating, it simply doesn't not work as the light is kept on.

I'm using 4 "IF" statement to control the light: auto light using Photo-resistor and serial value resumed in "ON/OFF", turn light on using serial value "h", turn light off using serial value "l" and another serial value to control the auto light statement using "a" to control the first statement.

How can I use a value to control light based on a sensor and serial output at the same time. In other words, how can I stop light from turning on automatically??  What I'm doing wrong or what I left?

Here is my simple code:

```
char val;

boolean setAuto=true; // Automatic Light Status Value 
int ldr; 
int relayPin=4;


void setup() {

   pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT);
   Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {

   ldr = analogRead(A0); // Read value from Photoresistor 

   if ( Serial.available()) {
      val = Serial.read(); // Get serial value
   }

   if ( setAuto == true && ldr < 50 ) { // Here is the main problem
      digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);
   }

   else if ( val == 'h' ) {
      digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH); // Work
   }       

   else if ( val == 'l') {
      digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW); // Work
   }

   else if (val == 'a') { // Here is the other part of the problem
     setAuto = !setAuto; // Changing value for automatic light
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first if statement:

```
 if ( setAuto == true && ldr < 50 ) { // Here is the main problem
     digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);
 } else {
```

takes precedence over the next two if statements.  Since setAuto is **ALWAYS** true and so when ldr < 50 the light thru relayPin is ON.

Think about how you might want to setAuto to false.

Hint.  You might want to evaluate `val` just after it is read:

```
if ( Serial.available()) {
  val = Serial.read(); // Get serial value
  if (val == ..... logic to affect the course of events.....
}
```

Comment: Well I tried something similar before but it seems that there is a problem with the last "else if" statement. I added a "Serial.print("Hey");" at the last statement and send the "a" but the one that runs is the second "else if" statement. Any idea on this particular behavior, that's crazy you know it doesn't make sense!

Comment: Thanks anyway I managed to work around something for now. I shifted the second and third "else if" statement and it worked pretty good. I don't know what happened as there were no errors in compilation time.

Comment: @DarkXDroid, debugging!!

Comment: I'm a newbie and I don't know much about debugging besides copy/paste error messages but as I said before: there were no errors in compilation time. All I can do is post the code already working, not the best code but well whatever...

Comment: @DarkXDroid, debugging is a learned skill, just like coding. Simplest method is to simply print values of variables at strategic points in your code.

Comment: Ohh well there's is no need for debugging but thanks anyway, maybe some mistake or bug in the arduino ide. I'll add some functions and information to replace the relay in exchange for a NPN transistor as a switch then post the code

Comment: @DarkXDroid, the Arduino supplies +5 volts to "relayPin".  I doubt if the problem is in the Arduino.  Also, an NPN transistor is **NOT** linear unless you bias it correctly.